# What do you call someone who substitutes one inappropriate word for a similar word?

Tags: meaning

Is there a term for someone who fails top distinguish one word from another, i.e. "ambidextrous" from "amphibian"?

Comment: So you saw that picture too? :-)

Comment: Is not your question more like: What do you call someone who substitutes one word for a similar but inappropriate word?

Answer (score 5):

You might be looking for "malapropist" as a personal form of "malapropism".

> [Malapropist](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/malapropist): a person who regularly makes malapropisms - Collins Dictionary
>
> [Malapropism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism): the use of an incorrect word in place of a word with a similar sound  - Wikipedia

Comment: The original of the word was a person: Mrs. Malaprop in Sheridan's *The Rivals*.

Comment: "Spoonerism" is another flavor of the same thing.

Comment: From the wikipedia link above, the origin is "... ultimately from the French _mal à propos_."

Comment: And what if someone does it on purpose for comedic effect? Is it still considered malapropism?

Comment: I don't think the definition of malapropism specifies whether the word swap must be deliberate or inadvertent, so I assume that either case applies.

Answer (score 3):

If the substitution is an accidental, and erroneous, substitution of a similar sounding word, such as "pineapple of perfection" instead of "pinnacle of perfection" the error is a "Malapropism", after Mrs. Malaprop, a character in Sheridan's *[The Rivals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rivals)*. The person who does it would be a "Malapropist".

If the substitution is a transposition of sounds, such as "queer old dean" for "dear old Queen", the error is a "Spoonerism", after [Rev. William Spooner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Archibald_Spooner), famed for making such errors. The person who does it would be a "Spoonerist", I suppose.

If the substitution is a deliberate substitution of a harmless word in place of an offensive one, such as "expecting" for "pregnant" -- standards for "offensive" used to be very different -- or the omission of the offensive word altogether, the change is a "Bowdlerism", after [Thomas Bowdler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bowdler), a publisher notorious for making such changes.  The person who does it would be a "Bowdlerizer".

If the substitution is a deliberate substitution of a similar sounding nonsense word in place of an offensive  exclamation, such as "Zounds!" for "God's wounds!", the replacement is a "minced oath".  The person who does it might be a "mincer".

Answer (score 2):

If it's a transposition of letters leading to a spoonerism (which are funnier the more inappropriate the result) the speaker [spoonerized](http://www.alphadictionary.com/goodword/word/spoonerism)