# Is there a term for a coined word that gives meaning by association?

Tags: terminology, phraseology

Bear with me as this is hard to articulate. Is there a word or term that describes when a coined word has obvious or intended meaning by being similar to another word, or having a certain "feel" to it? I'm thinking onomatopoeia but for *meaning*.

The best example I can think of from the top of my head is "Orgastic" in The Great Gatsby. Forgive me if I'm wrong, but the word is coined for the use, and while it's meaning is left ambiguous, you learn all you need to know about the meaning by the feel and similarity to the *other* word.

Full quote:

> Gatsby believed in the green light, the orgastic future that year by year recedes before us. It eluded us then, but that’s no matter—tomorrow we will run faster, stretch out our arms farther. . . . And then one fine morning—
>   So we beat on, boats against the current, borne back ceaselessly into the past.

Comment: I'm so  confused. I've taken a look at a number of dictionaries and they list "orgastic" as well as "orgasmic" as adjectival forms of "orgasm".  Also confer "orgastic potency". So not knowing the story or the context I have no clue whether they misspoke (meant to use "orgasmic" or "orgiastic") or used the correct word. Why would Gatsby call the future that recedes orgastic/orgasmic?

Comment: Just reread your question. I get the impression that you think the word "orgastic" doesn't exist but sounds like another word (that's what I thought). But it does exist as a variant spelling of "orgasmic". So if the character meant to mean "orgasmic" it's not a malaproprism. If the word "orgastic" didn't exist it also wouldn't be a malapropism either as per the definitions at Wikipedia and The Free Dictionary online, but a neologism or nonce word which sounds like a word that does exist.

Comment: Yes apologies. It was clearly a bad example, but got me the answer I was looking for anyway!

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/orgastic *Orgastic* is a **word**, not a coinage.

Comment: The question is based on a misconception.

Comment: Without some examples it is not at all clear what it is 'for a coined word [to give] meaning by association', and the only example given in the question is unclear. The OP acknowledged that it was a bad example, but seemed to have no interest in offering a better one, and has long ago stopped contributing to the site. It doesn't look like this page will ever be of any use to any future visitors to this site.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are describing is malaproprism. [I am not saying that is what is in The Great Gatsby]. Though it could be: orgiastic or orgasmic (preferred), I assume.

Wikipedia

> An instance of speech error is called a malapropism when a word is produced which is nonsensical or ludicrous in context, yet similar in sound to what was intended.[7]
>
> The fictional Mrs. Malaprop in Sheridan's play The Rivals utters many malapropisms. In Act 3 Scene III, she declares to Captain Absolute, "Sure, if I reprehend any thing in this world it is the use of my oracular tongue, and a nice derangement of epitaphs!"[11] This nonsensical utterance might, for example, be corrected to, "If I apprehend anything in this world, it is the use of my vernacular tongue, and a nice arrangement of epithets",[12] —although these are not the only words that can be substituted to produce an appropriately expressed thought in this context, and commentators have proposed other possible replacements that work just as well.

like using obtuse for abstruse

[malaproprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism)

Comment: What if it is like this, but intentional, and used stylistically? This is a very close answer, however.

Comment: @LeeDavison Well, that is very hard to tell, idnit? :) Here, it seems to be a variant. Whereas with malaproprism, it seems to be lack of knowledge or a lapsus.

Comment: The Wikipedia article continues: 'Malapropisms differ from other kinds of speaking or writing mistakes, such as eggcorns or spoonerisms, as well as the accidental or deliberate production of newly made-up 'words'. OP specifies a nonce usage, what I'd call a D-I-Y non-word. // [Malapropisms had been covered before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251631/what-do-you-call-someone-who-substitutes-one-inappropriate-word-for-a-similar-wo/251637#251637).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't think trying to give every single funny thing is necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Etymologically speaking... maybe? I think semantically, however, the word you are looking for is *double entendre*

> a word or phrase open to two interpretations, one of which is usually risqué or indecent

I should note that in your example, "orgastic" doesn't count as 'another word,' per se, it is the adjective suffix to orgas- / orgi-, at **orgasm**. :)

Comment: I had assumed the adjective would be "orgasmic", and therefore this word was chosen (or coined‽) due to the ambiguity and texture it gives. I can't see any other real use of the word aside from this.

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orgastic

Comment: If, as you acknowledge, *orgastic* 'doesn't count as "another word"', then how can this be a case of **double** entendre, which, by definition, involves two distinct meanings?